# Changing the port that the admin console runs on for Geronimo/WASCE

Tags: websphere

I am running WASCE version 2.1.1

I am trying to change the default port that the admin console runs on. I have seen it mentioned that default ports can be changed in the config.substitutions file but cant find anything related to the admin console port number.

Currently this is running on 443 as is my web application.

Thanks

Tom